# Why two different inline-block elemens go downwards, if we target only one of them

Tags: html, css

I have two html elements i.e label and anchor and both of them are inline. If I set their display property to `display: inline-block` and give label `margin-top` of 50px, why along with label, anchor tag is also moving? Here i have only targeted label.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Practise</title>
    <style>
      label{
          margin-top: 50px;
          display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <a href="#">iamlink</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both elements move because of the default `vertical-align` property. If you change the `vertical-align` to `top`, then you will be able to move the `label` only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Practise</title>
    <style>
      label{
          margin-top: 50px;
          display: inline-block;
      }
      a {
          vertical-align: top;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <a href="#">iamlink</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got your point. but the question is that why both of them are moving downwards, if i have targeted only label. isn't only label supposed to go downwards?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer.